# Using undefined as key in object

Tags: typescript

I use an object to map one value to another, e.g.

```
const wordToNumber = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
  three: 3,
}
```

But also I have a special case that when user tries to get a value by key `undefined` I want it to return `1` as well.

So I change the object to this:

```
const wordToNumber = {
  one: 1,
  two: 2,
  three: 3,
  [undefined]: 1,
}
```

And it works as expected in playground:

[image]

But TS complains on `undefined` key: `TS2464: A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.`

And I'm wondering is there anything wrong with using `undefined` as an object key or it's fine and I can just hide the complaint with `ts-ignore`?

Comment: Object keys are *only* strings or symbols. If you assign anything else as a key, it just gets converted to a string, so an undefined key is just the literal string `"undefined"`. However, TS doesn't like addressing non-string (and non-symbol) keys as most times it's assumed to be an error. You can use a `Map` which doesn't have a limit of key types or just type `"undefined"` literally as a key.

Comment: Given it's converted to a string, what's the benefit over using an `undefined` key instead?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the square brackets. This worked for me in JSFiddle

```
const wordToNumber = {
    one: 1,
    two: 2,
    three: 3,
    undefined: 1,
}

alert(wordToNumber["one"])
alert(wordToNumber[undefined])
```

Comment: For some reason I haven't.

But yeah, my bad, turns out there's no difference between `[undefined]` and `undefined`

Comment: To be type safe, and since `undefined` is a reserved word, consider this: `alert(wordToNumber["undefined"])`

Comment: 1. Nothing would change with or without the brackets. 2. TS will still complain about trying to use a non-string as key.

Comment: @VLAZ I was expecting the same. Running it in TSPlayground, it only complained when it is accessed: https://tsplay.dev/YmpbMw

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use map in this case (with get and set)?

```
const m = new Map();
m.set(undefined, "test");
console.log(m.get(undefined));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this.
I would do it like this:

```
const wordToNumber = (word) => {    
    if (typeof word !== "string") {
        return "1";
    }
    
    return {
        one: 1,
        two: 2,
        three: 3,
    }[word];
}

wordToNumber("one");
```

This returns `"1"` if the word is not a string, instead of looking for `undefined` specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Since javascript changes `undefined` into strings for object keys, I think that in this case it is likely safe, and ignoring the error may be ok. Here is my example use:

```js
enum LeftEnum {
    Required = 0,
    Hidden   = 1,
    Optional = 2
};

enum RightEnum {
    Required = 1,
    DontShow = 2,
    Optional = 3
};

type LeftObjectType = {
    Show?: LeftEnum
};

type RightObjectType = {
    Display: RightEnum
};

const convertLeftToRight = {
    [LeftEnum.Required]: RightEnum.Required as const,
    [LeftEnum.Hidden]:   RightEnum.DontShow as const,
    [LeftEnum.Optional]: RightEnum.Optional as const,
    undefined:           RightEnum.Optional as const
};

const lefts: LeftObjectType[] = [
    {},                      // undefined -> optional or 3
    {Show: LeftEnum.Hidden}, //         1 -> dontShow or 2
    {Show: LeftEnum.Required}, //       0 -> required or 1
    {Show: LeftEnum.Optional} // optional -> optional or 3
];

const newRight: RightObjectType[] = lefts.map(left => ({
    // Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type.(2538)
    Display: convertLeftToRight[left.Show]
}));

// produces correct results
console.log(newRight); 

// no error
const a: RightEnum.Optional = convertLeftToRight["undefined"];

// Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type.(2538)
const b: RightEnum.Optional = convertLeftToRight[undefined];
```

Since we know that the only use of `undefined` here is going to work out, an there is no chance of using `"undefined"` for a different meaning, it seems fine to bypass the check.

But I don't understand the reasoning banning the use of `undefined` for index types, since typescript seems to know that the keyword `undefined` works fine as a object key, because using `undefined` and `"undefined"` and `["undefined"]` cannot be used over each other throwing `An object literal cannot have multiple properties with the same name.(1117)`, but does not collide with the string `"Undefined"`:

```js
const convertLeftToRight= {
    [LeftEnum.Required]: RightEnum.Required as const,
    [LeftEnum.Hidden]: RightEnum.DontShow as const,
    [LeftEnum.Optional]: RightEnum.Optional as const,
    null: RightEnum.Optional as const,
    undefined: RightEnum.Optional as const,
    // An object literal cannot have multiple properties with the same name.(1117)
    ["undefined"]: RightEnum.Optional as const,
    // A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.(2464)
    [undefined]: RightEnum.Optional as const,
    // An object literal cannot have multiple properties with the same name.(1117)
    "undefined": RightEnum.Optional as const,
    // no error
    "Undefined": RightEnum.DontShow as const
};
```

The object documentation even shows the key as the blue reserved word `undefined` not the green string `"Undefined"`, or light green numbers.

[image: object documentation difference between number string null undefined]

even if the string `"undefined"` is used:

[image: object documentation for string undefined]